# Is there any way to obtain a random word from PyEnchant?

Tags: python

Is there a way to obtain a random word from PyEnchant's dictionaries?
I've tried doing the following:

```py
enchant.Dict("<language>").keys() #Type 'Dict' has no attribute 'keys'

list(enchant.Dict("<language>")) #Type 'Dict' is not iterable
```

I've also tried looking into the module to see where it gets its wordlist from but haven't had any success.

Using the separate "Random-Words" module is a workaround, but as it doesn't follow the same wordlist as PyEnchant, not all words will match. It is also quite a slow method. It is, however, the best alternative I've found so far.

Comment: it is special class which only has name `Dict` but it has nothing to do with standard dictionary. It seems it uses some C/C++ code to access words from special file - and this file can keep values encrypted or compressed - and it doesn't have method to get all words. But maybe you find something in [source code](https://github.com/pyenchant/pyenchant)

Comment: in [repo](https://github.com/pyenchant/pyenchant) you can see that `Enchant` can use different spellchecking packages - ie. `aspell`. And to get all words from `aspell` you can use console command `aspell dump master` . If you have many languages installed then `aspell -d <language_code> dump master` - ie. for Polish language `aspell -d pl dump master` (but first it needs to install `aspell-polish` - on Linux Mint/Ubuntu it needs `apt install aspell-polish`). More in [PyWordle](https://github.com/furas/pywordle/tree/main/dict). And when you will have list with all words then you can get random

Comment: Hi! I'm having double dumping because `'aspell' isn't recognized as a cmdlet, [...]` and I can't make it work because bzip2 refuses to work (can't untar the aspell dictionary without bzip2).
How do I access the english dictionary that aspell uses?
@furas
Edit: on windows

Comment: `aspell` is not standard program and you have to install it - see [home page](http://aspell.net/). There is link to [old version for windows](http://aspell.net/win32/). Or you may need to install [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) to have Linux environment on Windows and install/run aspell in this environment. Or maybe it will work in [WSL - Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/)

Comment: I added `dict-en.txt` to my repo [PyWordle](https://github.com/furas/pywordle/tree/main/dict)

Comment: Thank you, this resolved my problem. 
I was able to filter out words that aren't in pyenchant's dictionary with some quick code. The ~80000 words left are more than enough for what I need them for. I really appreciate you taking the time to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of @furas this question has been resolved.

Using the dict-en text file in furas' [PyWordle](https://github.com/furas/pywordle/tree/main/dict), I wrote a short code that filters out invalid words in pyenchant's wordlist.

```py
import enchant

wordlist = enchant.Dict("en_US")

baseWordlist = open("dict-en.txt", "r")
lines = baseWordlist.readlines()
baseWordlist.close()

newWordlist = open("dict-en_NEW.txt", "w") #write to new text file
for line in lines:
    word = line.strip("\n")

    if wordList.check(word) == True: #if word exists in pyenchant's dictionary
        print(line + " is valid.")
        newWordlist.write(line)
    else:
        print(line + " is invalid.")

newWordlist.close()
```

Afterwards, calling the text file will allow you to gather the information in that line.

```py
validWords = open("dict-en_NEW", "r")
wordList = validWords.readlines()

myWord = wordList[<line>] 
#<line> can be any int (max is .txt length), either a chosen one or a random one. 
#this will return the word located at line <line>.
```

Answer (score 2):

Your question really got me curious so I thought of some way to make a random word using `enchant`.

```
import enchant
import random
import string

# here I am getting hold of all the letters

letters = string.ascii_lowercase

# crating a string with a random length with random letters

word = "".join([random.choice(letters) for _ in range(random.randint(3, 8))])

d = enchant.Dict("en_US")

# using the `enchant` to suggest a word based on the random string we provide

random_word = d.suggest(word)
```

Sometimes the `suggest` method will not return any suggestion so you will need to make a loop to check if `random_word` has any value.